# an Assert that accept anything and then check if there exist an exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java, TestNG and Selenium to write a test. I was wondering if we have an Assert type that I can put **anything** in it and then if it throws an exception the assert print the message something like:

```
Assert.something(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
(By.xpath("//button[text()='Add Representative']"))).click());
```

I already know that I can use Try and Catch like:

```
try{
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
    (By.xpath("//button[text()='Add Representative']"))).click();
}catch(Exception e){
    Assert.assertFalse(true, "this clcik did not work");
}
```

buy I was wondering if i could use it in a way that i showed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following two methods for this case:

```
public static void assertNull(java.lang.Object object, java.lang.String message)
```

As click command returns null when element is clicked, you can assert with null and pass any message to Assert that you want to print on failure.

Or

```
public static void assertThrows(Assert.ThrowingRunnable runnable)
```

This will assert that the function throws an exception or not.

You can refer [testng assert](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/Assert.html) class and its method for more details.
Hope this helps.